# Why I can't call packagename.modulename.foo()?

Tags: python, import, package

In my working python directory I create:

```
packagename/__init__.py
packagename/modulename.py
test.py
```

In modulename.py I create some empty class:

```
class Someclass(object):
   pass
```

in test.py:

```
import packagename
packagename.modulename.Someclass()
```

Why I can't call packagename.modulename.someclass() in test.py ?

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'modulename'
```

I understand that the right way is:

```
import packagename.modulename
```

or

```
from packagename import modulename
```

But I do not understand why I get this error in my case.

**Update:**

In other words is there any way to import a package's content with all modules in the distinct namespace? 
I need correct pythonic expression for:

```
from packagename import * as mynamespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had 100 modules in the "packagename" package, would you want them all to be imported automatically when you imported just the top-level name?  That wouldn't usually be a good idea, so Python doesn't do it.

If you want to have that particular module imported automatically, just include it in the `__init__.py` like so:

```
from packagename import modulename
```

Alternatively, using Python 2.5 or 2.6:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import modulename
```

(In later versions, you can ditch the `from __future__` part.)

**Edit**: there is no built-in mechanism to ask Python to import all possible submodules inside a package.  That's not a common use case, and it's better handled explicitly by having your `__init__.py` import precisely those things that you want.  It would be possible to put something together to do the job (using `__import__()` and such) but it is better in most cases just to explicitly import all submodules as described.

Comment: I need list all packages's modules in packagename/__init_.py, right?

I think I need correct python expression for "from packagename import * as mynamespace".

Comment: I think that's spelled simply `import packagename as mynamespace`.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not automatically recurse and import subpackages.  When you say:

```
import packagename
```

That is all it imports.  If you say:

```
import packagename.modulename
```

Then it first imports `packagename`, then imports `packagename.modulename` and **assignes a reference to it** as an attribute of `packagename`.  Therefore, when you say in code:

```
packagename.modulename.Someclass()
```

Python is just using **100% normal** attribute lookups.  First lookup the `packagename` variable in the current namespace.  Then lookup the `modulename` attribute of the `packagename` object.  Then lookup the `Someclass` attribute of the `modulename` object.

If you neglected to import `packagename.modulename`, then there is plainly **no attribute** on `packagename` called `modulename`, and henceforth the `AttributeError`.

I suggest you pop onto the command line and import something, then use `dir()` to examine it.  Then import a subpackage, and use `dir()` again.  You will quickly see the difference.

---

Lastly, the syntax:

```
from packagename.modulename import SomePackage
```

Is essentially the same as this:

```
import packagename.modulename
SomePackage = packagename.modulename.SomePackage
```

(of course, it's implemented differently, but more or less the same result).

Does that help?

Comment: @gahooa: Thank you for your answer, but is there any way to import all modules from package in separate namespace? Something like "import packagename.*"

Answer (score 0):

Some packages are very large and importing everything within them would take a lot of time. It's better to offer fine granularity for imports, so the user only imports what he really needs.